# Selenium: Dependency injection does not work

Tags: java, spring, selenium, cucumber

In my java spring mvc, I am trying to make test using cucumber nad selenium.
I have the following class, which is responsible for invoking the driver.

```
@Service
public class BaseUtil {

  public void caller(){
      System.out.println("Caller Firefox driver here!!!!!!!");
  }

}
```

and then in step definition class i am going to make the dependency injection into the steps:

```
 @Component
public class StepDefenitions{

    @Autowired
     BaseUtil base;


    @Given("^I want to register into the main forum$")
    public void i_want_to_register_into_the_main_forum() throws Throwable {
        base.caller();

    }}
```

But it complains with

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.exercise.StepDefenitions.i_want_to_register_into_the_main_forum(StepDefenitions.java:26)
```

So, why the `@Autowierd` does not work here?

Comment: Is `StepDefenitions` a spring managed bean?

Comment: Jens is right. Do you have @Component or @ Service on StepDefinitions class

Comment: no it contains the steps of the feature file of cucumber. But, i am not sure if i answer ur question @Jens

Comment: @Salman Autowiring only works in spring managed beans. So if `StepDefenitions` isn't one, autowiring can not work

Comment: so, is there anyway that i can make the defined `StepDefenitions` as a spring managed bean?

Comment: Do you have the cucumber.xml which tells spring base packages to scan for classes that are going to be injected? -- <context:component-scan base-package="....." />. Try this and maybe this works - Remove the Component annotation from StepDefinition class. Replace the Service annotation with Component annotation and add below it Scope("cucumber-glue").

Comment: You can make it very simpler by utilizing selenium specific frameworks like https://github.com/qmetry/qaf which takes care of driver configuration and other black-box testing needs. See https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-step-by-step-tutorial/wiki

Answer (score 0):

StepDefenitions needs to be a managed bean to have its dependencies injected.

Annotate it with @Component or @Service.

Comment: I have updated my question with ur solution. I have tried both `@Service` and `@Component` both of them failed

Comment: are you using @Configuration or xml for bean definition?

Comment: i have none of them right now. so, i think, i can have both of them